# Begriffe die historische, einschneidende Ereignisse/Zeiten beschreiben?

Tags: idiom, phrase-request

Fallen jemand außer

> Zäsur, epochales Ereignis, Zeitenwende

noch andere Begriffe/Akjektive/Fremdwörter ein, die für diesen Zweck verwendet werden können?

Comment: [OpenThesaurus](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/z%C3%A4sur) findet Bruch, Einschnitt, Wendepunkt, Unterbrechung. Davon abgesehen denke ich allerdings, dass diese Synonym-Frage off-topic ist, ähnlich wie Übersetzungsanfragen.

Comment: @jan Danke für *Bruch* Ich beanspruche mal die Ausnahme von der Regel für mich ;) So oft stell ich solche Fragen ja nicht. Mögen tu ich sie auch nicht, Übersetzungsanfragen wie die von Tom Au find ich ok, solange wir keine Lyrics Exegese Zirkel hier werden :) Mir gehts bei der Frage um eine möglichst vollständige Liste von Phrasen und Synonymen zwecks Recherche. Wir haben hier gerade mal 11 fragen mit phrase request getagged, auf ELU haben sie an 1000 single-word-request und davon ist der Grossteil weit unterirdischer als das hier.

Comment: @jan http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44776/the-friend-who-has-the-same-dream Der Sinn und warum solche Fragen nicht geschlossen werden leuchtet mir garnicht ein, denn keines der angebotenen Wörter kann man wirklich direkt so verstehen, dass der Freund die gleichen Lebensträume hat. Es wird nur umparaphrasiert

Comment: in meinen Augen ist der Unterschied zwischen Deinem Beispiel aus ELU und Deiner Frage hier, dass bei Deiner Frage ein *Thesaurus* weiterhelfen kann - das ist bei längeren Phrasen nicht unbedingt der Fall. Mein Bauchgefühl bewertet die Fragen danach, wie viel Aufwand oder Wissen nötig ist, um sie zu beantworten, und wenn der Aufwand lediglich eine Google-Suche, dict.leo-, Duden- oder (Open)Thesaurus-Abfrage *mit genau dem Wort* ist, dann sehe ich das halt eher kritisch.

Comment: @jan Thesaurus/-en? sind nur meist nicht vollständig, darum gings mir ja. Hatte obige Begriffe ja nachgeschlagen bevor ich hier fragte. Zeitenwende fehlt bei deinem Link z.B. Aber stimm dir ja zu das solche Fragen grenzwertig und nicht die Regel werden sollten wie auf ELU. Der Freund mit dem gleichen Traum ist ja nicht wirklich ne schneidende oft benutzte Phrase, warum man dafür ein einzeles Wort wie "Comrade/Genosse" (rein politisch) verwenden sollte, entzieht sich mir. Das versteht kein Mensch so wie es Frager andeutet. Solche Fragen findet man aber zuhauf momentan auf ELU

Comment: dann war *das* vielleicht die entscheidende Information, die mir gefehlt hat: Du hattest bereits in einem oder mehreren Thesauriern ( ;) ) nachgeschlagen, warst aber unzufrieden mit dem Ergebnis. Ich denke, das setzt dann auch die Messlatte für die Antworten etwas höher, und wäre dann in meinen Augen auch eher wieder OK für German.SE. Vielleicht wäre hier eine Diskussion auf Meta sinnvoll.

Comment: @jan brauchen wir denke ich nicht, solange solche Fragen nicht sehr viele Upvotes wie auf ELU generieren funktioniert das System hier ja. Aber wenn GLU wächst, bekommen wir wohl ähnliche Probleme.Zum Glück ist Deutsch schwierig zu lernen :P und nicht jeder muss es zwangsläufig sprechen.Aus dieser Ausnahme der Regel wieder auf Meta eine Regel zu bauen ist imo überflüssig, zumal sie dort sowieso nur ein Dutzend mitbekommt.Dann lieber CW für online-Thesaurier hier.Auf ELU scheint mir das mehr Rep-Gaming zu sein, der Nutzen der Antworten entzieht sich mir bei den meisten single requests (again).

Answer (score 4):

- Wendepunkt
- Revolution

Comment: Revolution hab ich jetzt auch schon vermehrt mit *Revolution fehlgeschlagen* gelesen. Das muss also implizit und retrospektiv nicht heissen, dass es einscheidend war. Kann ich aber jetzt nicht beurteilen ob Historiker Revolution nur benutzen wenn sie auch erfolgreich war? +1 für Wendepunkt

Comment: Wie meinen? Wenn es kein epochales Ereignis, keine Revolution, kein Wendepunkt war, dann passt der Begriff nicht? Das liegt aber doch an der Negation, nicht am Begriff selbst. Oder verstehe ich da was nicht? Was ist denn bei einem 'scheinbaren Wendepunkt' anders, als bei einer fehlgeschlagenen Revolution?

Comment: Hast Recht. War wohl Haarspalterei, überleg gerade ob in der Geschichte Revolutionen mit Eigennamen wie "Oktoberrevolution" (die hat ja geklappt) als solche tituliert wurden, aber fehlschlugen. Wikipedia verneint aber auf die Schnelle. Bei Zeitenwende/Zäsur würde man (ich) aber nicht irgend ein nivillierendes/negierendes adjektiv davorschreiben, das ist imo ne feine Nuance, Wendepunkt/Bruch/Zäsur haben rein retrospektiven Charakter, "fehlgeschlagene Zäsur" ist sinnlos. Was an Revolution in dem retrosp. Kontext nicht stimmt, ist das sie immer aktiv(Menschen) ist, aber nicht passiv beschreibt...

Comment: Na ja, es gibt schon Revolutionen der Art "Der König ist tot - es lebe der König", wo sich nichts ändert, außer dem Namen des Despoten. Für den, und seine Clique ist es natürlich schon ein gewaltiger Unterschied, ob er an der Macht ist oder nicht. Wenn nur die Figur wechselt ist es eher ein Putsch - die sowj. Revolution war wohl eine Umwälzung in vielerlei Hinsicht, auch wenn in einigen wichtigen Punkten die Ziele verfehlt wurden. Dieses Scheitern wäre zu unterscheiden vom militärischen Scheitern; dass sie niedergeworfen wird.

Answer (score 2):

- [Paradigmenwechsel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Paradigmenwechsel)